How to enumerate categories with formula in Google Sheets
I'm struggling to get solution for my simple task in Google Sheets:
I want to use formula to enumerate categorical data from 1 to number of entries in category, then starting from 1 for next category etc. Data is already sorted
I've tried SCAN function like =SCAN(0; A:A; LAMBDA(counter; current; IF(INDEX(A:A; ROW()-1)=current); counter+1;1))) but problem is counter doesnt restart from 1 from the next category.
result should be like this:
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 1
B 2
C 1
C 2
C 3

You can try:
=MAP(A1:A,LAMBDA(_,IF(_="",,COUNTIF(A1:_,_)))) 


Without LAMBDA:
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(a,A:A,r,ROW(a),IF(a="",,COUNTIFS(a,a,r,"<="&r)))) 


That's brilliant! I've came to solution with COUNTIFS too. but including another column with sales data sorted desc.

Here's something you can try, considering the data is already sorted.
=let(
  z,tocol(,1),
  categories,unique(tocol(A:A,1)),
    breakout,map(categories,lambda(k,countif(A:A,k))),
      reduce(z,breakout,lambda(a,c,vstack(a,sequence(c,1,1,1)))))

